# How can I simplify $(1+i)^n - (1+k)^n$, for natural $n$ and real $i$ and $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression:
$$
(1+i)^n - (1+k)^n 
$$
where $i$ and $k$ are real numbers and $n$ is a natural number. Do you know how could I simplify this term?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

From the binominal theorem, do you know that $$(1+x)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n {n\choose r} x^r$$
If yes, you'll get $$(1+i)^n - (1+k)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n {n\choose r} i^r - \sum_{r=0}^n {n\choose r} k^r\\= \sum_{r=1}^{n} {n\choose r} (i^r - k^r)$$
I don't know if this simplifies or complicates it for you, but this is probably the best you can get with this expression. If you're looking to factorize the expression somehow, try using $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\dots+a^2b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right)$$ with $a = 1+i$ and $b = 1+k$. Hope this helps!